# React Native - zIndex

Tags: styles, react-native, z-index

I try to make `FlatList` where circles are different sizes, for each cirle, i need to have own `zIndex`.

[image]

Numbers in circles, show zIndex number, as you see its not working.

I use zIndex on `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>`

Here is my component:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={() => dispatch(selectHockeyPlayer(item))}
        style={[
          styles.listItem,
          {
            width: playerWidth,
            height: playerWidth,
            transform: [{scale: scaleNum + 1.2}],
            zIndex: Math.floor(scaleNum + 2),
          },
          isRated ? styles.isRated : null,
          styles.circle,
          activePlayer(item, styles.selectedListItem),
        ]}>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, i figured out what was the problem, `FlatList` doesnt work with zIndex, so i had to use `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

> Place a View inside of TouchableWithoutFeedback and apply TouchableWithoutFeedback styles to the View
>
> > Do this

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={() => dispatch(selectHockeyPlayer(item))}>
        <View
          style={[
          styles.listItem,
          {
            width: playerWidth,
            height: playerWidth,
            transform: [{scale: scaleNum + 1.2}],
            zIndex: Math.floor(scaleNum + 2),
          },
          isRated ? styles.isRated : null,
          styles.circle,
          activePlayer(item, styles.selectedListItem),
        ]}>
```